# How to find the next line in the nsstring

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is there any way to find the next line characters in the NSString. I mean the second line of characters.

I am using

```
NSString *substring = [text substringToIndex:[text rangeOfString:@"            "].location];
```

I want to find out that empty space in the entire text. I'm able to find that empty space in the first line of NSString, but in the second line also contains the same empty space.

Answer (score 7):

You can split on `\n` character.

Something like this:

```
NSArray *vals = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then check if `vals` has more than one element.

```
if ([vals count] > 1) {
    // you do have a "next line"
    NSString *nextLine = [vals objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSLog(nextLine);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to split.. i just want to find the coordinates of particular character.. that character is in the second line of text.

Comment: You need to split in order to check the **second line**. Other possibility might be parsing the string yourself. But that's a little bit more code than the one I showed.

Comment: you should use [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] instead of \n.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *lines = [yourNSStringObject componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *secondline = [lines objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload method for rangeOfString that you can provide a range for it.

Try this:

```
NSString *substring = [text substringToIndex:[text rangeOfString:@" " options:nil range:NSMakeRange([text rangeOfString:@"\n"], text.length)].location];
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is using `next` and `second` interchangeably, which actually are not the same.

Just in case, if anyone is looking for a code snippet for the `next` line, then here it is

```swift
extension StringProtocol {
    func nextLineRange(at index: Index) -> Range<Index>? {
        let firstLineRange = lineRange(at: index)
        if self.endIndex == firstLineRange.upperBound {
            print("Already on the last line")
            return nil
        }
        let nextChar = self.index(after: firstLineRange.upperBound)
        return lineRange(at: nextChar)
    }
}
```

Unlike other solutions, this one does not split the entire string in to an array of String.

---

This solution can be used to extract the second line as well

```swift
let secondLineRange = text.nextLineRange(at: text.startIndex)
```